# Add any username as link prefix and show data from that specific user’s profile on wordpress pages – with no login required

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Example: [www.example.com/johndoe/sample-page/](http://www.example.com/johndoe/sample-page/)

User with username “johndoe” has

1. Name field value of “John Doe”
2. E-mail field value of “johndoe@email.com”
3. Facebook field value of  “facebook.com/johndoe”
4. Address field value of “Main street 47 ”

Show this values on Sample Page via shortcode
`[userdata username={read_from_url} field=email]`

Once opened, save this username in a cookie and redirect the visitor:
[www.example.com/sample-page/](http://www.example.com/sample-page/) --> [www.example.com/username/sample-page/](http://www.example.com/username/sample-page/)

Add that USERNAME to all internal links to avoid redirects (from there on every active link on the website to contain the prefix)

Live example with the same functionality on another wordpress site: https://eqology.com/15499949/webshop/our-products-en/omega-3-en/
(Check CTRL+U to see all internal links contain the username/id prefix)

I've tried creating a rewrite tag and a rule for it to be put in a url param
`add_rewrite_tag('%username%', '([^&]+)', 'username=');`

Then use URL Params shortcode
[urlparam param='username'] but I know it's not suppossed to work this way :D

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to obtain. If you want to make an author page you should modify rewrite rules to simplify the url structure (to remove "author" from Wordpress author pages) and then use the auhtor.php template to customize your author page.

Comment: I want to add any username to the wordpress URL as a prefix, then be able to show profile field values via shortcode anywhere on the page.

Comment: It is like an affiliate parameter in the url (pretty) but also can match some data with it based on username call user profile fieds... How else could I put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it :D :D :D Received $1000 offers to create this plugin and some failed in delivering it; Got so much from the wp community I'll share it without comments.

**functions.php**

```
add_action('init', 'eqid_url_rewrite');
function eqid_url_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*)/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?eqid=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[2]','top');
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'eqid_query_var' );
function eqid_query_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'eqid';
    return $vars;
}
 
add_action( 'wp', 'eqid_cookie' );
function eqid_cookie(){
    $eqid = get_query_var('eqid');
    if($eqid) {
        $eqbp = get_user_by('login', $eqid);
        
        if (isset($eqbp->user_login))
            setcookie('eqid_cookie', $eqid, strtotime('+90 days'), '/'); 
    }

    $prefix_slug_wslash = "bp/";

    if(($_COOKIE['eqid_cookie']) && (!$eqid) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== "/" && (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$prefix_slug_wslash) == true) && (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$_COOKIE['eqid_cookie']) == false) && !is_admin()) {
        wp_redirect( "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$_COOKIE['eqid_cookie']."/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        exit;
    }
}


function eqid_shortcode(){
    $eqid = get_query_var('eqid');
    //$eqid = $_COOKIE['eqid_cookie'];
    if($eqid) 
        $eqbp = get_user_by('login', $eqid);

    return $eqbp->user_login;
}
add_shortcode( 'eqbp_id', 'eqid_shortcode' );

function eqid_shortcode_nev(){
    $eqid = get_query_var('eqid');
    //$eqid = $_COOKIE['eqid_cookie'];
    if($eqid)
        $eqbp = get_user_by('login', $eqid);

    return $eqbp->first_name." ".$eqbp->last_name;
}
add_shortcode( 'eqbp_nev', 'eqid_shortcode_nev' );
```

**author.php**

```
if( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ){   die();  }

$eqid = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1, -1);
if ($eqid)
    setcookie('eqid_cookie', $eqid, strtotime('+90 days'), '/'); 

wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit;
```

Above script works for all sub-pages of $prefix_slug_wslash = "bp/";
You can remove that and it will work for all pages.

After opening link like: example.com/username cookie is set and the page will redirect to home. I've added this to header top bar with a shortcode or you can put it in child theme header.php also

```
//Header Site badge tag [shortcode]
function eqid_headersitebadgetag(){
    $eqid = get_query_var('eqid');
    
    if(!$eqid)
        $eqid = $_COOKIE['eqid_cookie'];
     
    if($eqid) {
        $eqbp = get_user_by('login', $eqid);
        
        if (isset($eqbp->user_login))
            return "<strong>".$eqbp->first_name." ".$eqbp->last_name."</strong> <em>(".$eqbp->nickname.")</em>";
    }
    return;
}
add_shortcode( 'eqbp_sheader', 'eqid_headersitebadgetag' );
```

For posts I needed the author slug in the link:

Permalinks structure: /%author%/%postname%/

```
function _eqid_shortcode(){
    return get_the_author_meta( 'login' );
}
add_shortcode( '_eqbp_id', '_eqid_shortcode' );
```

This is more like having an affiliate name masked in a pretty url which will be kept across navigation and you can show affiliate specific info on pages with shortcodes without the need of login from other users.